# How to print keys and values from a text file

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8.7

I have a file called "output.txt":

```
    "name": "abc",
    "age": 28,
    "name": "xxx",
    "age": 11,
    "name": "yyyb",
    "age": 15,
```

I want to read the file and print the name and age values on one line, one after the other:

```
abc 28
xxx 11
yyyb 15
```

The code I wrote is:

```
  file_data = {}
   object= File.open('output.txt', 'r') do |file|
   file.each_line do |line|  
   key,value = line  
   file_data[value] = key
   puts file_data
```

I am getting:

```
{nil=>"    \"name\": \"abc"\",\n"}
{nil=>"    \"age\": 28,\n"}
{nil=>"    \"name\": \"11"\",\n"}
{nil=>"    \"age\": false,\n"}
{nil=>"    \"name\": \"yyyb\",\n"}
{nil=>"    \"age\": 15,\n"}
```

Comment: Don't assign the line to two variables and put it in a hash and print that. Just parse it (probably with a regular expression) and print the parts you want.

Comment: Why aren't you using a yaml file?

Comment: Yes, it's far better to use YAML or JSON because it makes outputting and parsing trivially simple.  You shouldn't be hand coding formatting and parsing if it can be done for you.

Comment: @ Dave Schweisguth can you please give the example of the code .

Comment: Hi all i am using ruby 1.8.7 which is there on our servers --with using json it is giving an error cannot parse it. so trying on another way

Comment: _Sidenote_: storing an input in hash leads to the incomplete result because of duplicated keys. Do you want just to print input out, or you need to store it somehow?

Comment: @ mudasobwa i want to print it out

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This looks like an XY problem, where you're asking about Y but should ask about X, which would be "How can I store the data from a hash?"

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use some popular format like `YAML` or `JSON` so you can work with it using some library. Also you could achieve it with code like this:

```
file_data = ""
object= File.open('output.txt', 'r') do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    key, value = line.split(':').map{|e| e.strip.gsub(/(,|\")/,'')}
    file_data << (key == 'name' ? "#{value} " : "#{value}\n")
  end
end
puts file_data
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i can see the only the last hash from the file. the output {"name" => "yyyb", "age" => 15"} cannot see other values from teh file

Comment: @user1642224 what do you want to have as an output?

Answer (score 0):

```
File.read('output.txt')
    .split(/\s*,\s*/)
    .each_slice(2)
    .each do |name, age|
  puts [name[/(?<=: ").*(?=")/], age[/(?<=: ).*/]].join ' '
end
```

Comment: @ mudasobwa I am get the output in this format                                                              name abc
    age 28
    name xxx
    age 11
    name yyyb
    age 15  . But i need to be in this format abc 28
xxx 11
yyyb 15

Comment: Oh indeed. Sorry. Updated.